# make FiddlerCore not get all the url's in a session

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

My apologies if the Caption for this question is inappropriate.

When I use FiddlerCore tocapture the urls visited, I get all the list of urls including links to the .js .css .ico and other files. I just want single url like in google chrome history.

Answer (score 0):

in a session Callback routine place an if condition

```
if(sess.ResponseHeaders.ToString().Contains("Content-Type: text/html")
{
    Console.WriteLine(sess.fullUrl.ToLower());
}
```

This will reduce the unnecessary urls.

sess is the parameter to your callback routine like

```
SessionCompletionCallback(Session sess )
{
}
```